# Fill Down a value in Pandas once it has occurred

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to Pandas and I am struggling to fill down a value once it has occurred. This is hard to explain, so I will show an example. This is the output of my code at the moment.

```
Cont_No Mnth    Short   Reset   Outst   Total   Default
6293    1       249.17  1       249.17  747.51  0
6293    2       249.17  0       498.34  747.51  0
6293    3       249.17  0       747.51  747.51  1
6293    4       -43.53  0       703.98  747.51  0
6293    5       -292.7  0       411.28  747.51  0
6294    1       0       1       0       800.00  0
6294    2       0       0       0       800.00  0
6294    3       0       0       0       800.00  0
6294    4       0       0       0       800.00  0
```

It represents different loans, and the amount short-paid each month. Once the outstanding balance on the loan (Outst) is greater than or equal to the "Total" column, the "Default" column becomes 1. When the outstanding balance falls below the "Total", the "Default" column returns to 0 (as it should, since I am using a >= in my code).

However, once the "Default" becomes 1, I would like it to remain there for the duration of the contract (in this case until line 5).

(The "Reset" column, is programmed to be 1 for the first month of a new loan, and 0 everywhere else.)

I would really appreciate if someone could please explain how to do this. I tried by using max() on the Default column, but after 4 hours it was still running (the rest of my code takes about 10 min in total to run).

Comment: Code snippets are for runnable HTML+CSS+JS, not just code formatting. For that use the {} button at the top after highlighting the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good solution for `cummax`:

```
df['Default'] = df.groupby('Cont_No')['Default'].cummax()
```

Output:

```
   Cont_No  Mnth   Short  Reset   Outst   Total  Default
0     6293     1  249.17      1  249.17  747.51        0
1     6293     2  249.17      0  498.34  747.51        0
2     6293     3  249.17      0  747.51  747.51        1
3     6293     4  -43.53      0  703.98  747.51        1
4     6293     5 -292.70      0  411.28  747.51        1
5     6294     1    0.00      1    0.00  800.00        0
6     6294     2    0.00      0    0.00  800.00        0
7     6294     3    0.00      0    0.00  800.00        0
8     6294     4    0.00      0    0.00  800.00        0
```